# stuck at busy box, attempt to boot old linux at another partition

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, initrd

I have, and able to boot with arch Linux with kernel 5.10.34 normally.
I have older Linux (linuxmint 20.1) on my sda6 with kernel 5.4.0-72 and 5.8.0-50. I am using [grub-customizer](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/grub-customizer/).
Kindly not answer with having live cd.

The strange thing is:

- when I tried to boot to my sda6 is, the /etc/fstab empty.
- it stuck at busybox(initramfs) with, /init exist.
- the exiting from the initramfs resulting kernel panic not sync.

```
run init: can't execute '': no such directory
kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
CPU 0 PID 1 Comm run-init Not Tainted 5.8.0-50 generic # 56~20.04.1-Ubuntu
call trace omitted: assuming just the panic that significant
```

- last time I use the Linux mint, I open a terminal with sudo on /var/www/somedir/, strangely the kernel was misplaced there.

what i have tried:

- using ridinit=/bin/sh (i missing the unix.stack q)
- manually copy /etc/fstab from arch to /etc/fstab busybox
- disable the [selinux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/822327/debugging-kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init)

[the old fstab](https://gist.github.com/sukrosono/db90a6142e34677d66b7cf299bf77858) before installing arch Linux (Manjaro).

detail about the busybox
`BusyBox v1.30.1 Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.3`

[/sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg](https://gist.github.com/sukrosono/f9525398803c8f5e2e0c817c2b5589db)

having said that, my question is how to create a permanent grub config so I am able to boot to my linuxmint properly?

### Amend

[blkid](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sukrosono/d518d7ec058147fa8a1fc6b48326deb3/raw/5d9a87615d403c3e594ebfcac4f38bfcf1edf948/arch.blkid.md)

[lsblik](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sukrosono/e9b2c8825a361df9924aeb360b7b9b56/raw/d3701b498690b28b48600be2b18d72e995b4fdc2/lsblk.md)

executing `ash init` from initramfs resulting:

[image]
cat init:
[image: result of cat]
/init:
[image: /init]
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to regenerate the grub config in Arch, i.e. install [`os-prober`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB#Detecting_other_operating_systems), 
mount `/dev/sda6` and run [`grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB#Generate_the_main_configuration_file)?

Comment: I forgot to mention on the question, I assume the os-prober is included on grub-customizer.

Comment: Hi, thou hast summoned me. ;) Could you run `lsblk` and `blkid` and tell me which are your mint partitions (boot and root)? And your current `grub.cfg`? Also, did you run `grub-mkconfig`?

Comment: it's the dev/sda6, I will update the q, no i just using the grub-customizer.

Comment: Thanks, but could you still run `sudo grub-mkconfig`. It wont change your configuration, it'll (try to) detect all available OS's and just write the config to `stdout`. Then we can compare it to your current `grub.cfg`

Comment: And I'll need the grub settings for mint in some form. Either `grub.cfg` or the config in `grub-customizer` should do.

Comment: Recently I had a problem like this I think where it wouldn't boot - if you are able to go to boot into advanced options, select recovery, select DPKG and then boot it might work. Let me know how it goes, good luck

Comment: There are no advanced options, and what do you mean by DPKG? I am trying to boot into debian.

Comment: I update q to mentioning the grub.cfg, when on initramfs I can't find where is the `grub-mkconfig` binary/ executable.

Comment: @AdiPrasetyo I think DPKG means DPKG but you will know what I mean when I see it, it is a very basic menu on a blue background. The advanced options should be there when you boot - what happens when you turn it on? Does it give you 2 or 3 boot options (one saying normal boot?)

Answer (score 0):

Yet, the whole partition on my sda6 is kinda repositioned, sorry for the lack of a better term.
My long desperation is paid because, no actual data loss. Just all the important file (the `/`) is moved to cwd when I am doing upgrade as long as I remember it.

[image]

I hope this q can stay open, expecting some insight from the community. Even the main trigger of this kind of failure is unclear. I tried copying `/` from a live cd it won't make the partition bootable.